# What does "account for a substantial proportion of world trade" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From [Diplomacy: A Very Short Introduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=i0sTiwJQMi0C&pg=PT160&lpg=PT160&dq=%22Transnational%20companies%20routinely%20transfer%20materials,%20components,%20and%20completed%20products%20across%20national%20boundaries%22&source=bl&ots=0eqkrg-O9L&sig=Y_GYu8C8zX5erYwYUOxMg8tOt_c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi31JPIgenLAhVD6WMKHQLOCIAQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%22Transnational%20companies%20routinely%20transfer%20materials%2C%20components%2C%20and%20completed%20products%20across%20national%20boundaries%22&f=false)

> Transnational companies routinely transfer materials, components, and completed products across national boundaries, and these ‘internal’ transfers **account for a substantial proportion of world trade**.

What does *"account for a substantial proportion of world trade"* mean here?

Comment: Which word(s) are you not sure about?

Comment: yorgun - I added a citation and fixed some formatting.  Take a look at the formatting/linking codes (by clicking "edit") and use them in the future!

Answer (score 2):

People normally think of trade as transactions between companies in different countries: ABCo in America sells 6000 widgets to DEFirm in Denmark.  Trade!

This writer is suggesting that sometimes ABC has a division in more than one country.  If it builds a bunch of widget parts in Canada, then ships them to America to be assembled into widgets, that should be considered "international trade" also.  It is "internal" because it happens within a single transnational copmany - They move profits from America to Canada, and widget parts from Canada to America without ever buying or selling anything.

Further, the bold part asserts that this type of "trade" is a large fraction of all international trade.  (The rest of which, one presumes is companies buying and selling things to each other.)

Comment: doy you mean that this "INTERNAL trade" seen as "EXTERNAL trade" in total word trade annual?

Comment: "Internal trade" is often used to mean movement of goods/services/wealth within a single _country._  That is NOT how it is being used here.  It is movement of goods/services/wealth within a single _company._  The company (regardless of geography) defines the boundary between internal and external.  This type of trade (**intra**-company/inter-national)  is then considered along with inter-company/inter-national trade as part of the total inter-national trade balance.

Answer (score 0):

it means that internal transfer(opposed to international transfer, both compose world trade), have relatively and considerable large part of world trade, or is important part of world trade.